# Prepend 'www' to an HTTPS url using .htaccess & mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dilemma with this one. With the following code I am able to force SSL on any non SSL url, however when the user (and results from Google) take the user to http://mysite.co.za then we hit an issue as the url is then rewritten to https://mysite.co.za

Due to the fact that my certificate is bound to www.mysite.co.za it immediately throws a security error because of the missing 'www' in the url.

Can someone point out a way to add the www to the domain when the domain starts with HTTPS and not HTTP?

Much appreciated.

And the current code to add the https:// is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're always going to have at least one warning even with a redirect. This is because the browser checks the SSL certificate before server gets to the point of redirecting

Comment: Redirect to www THEN redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: @Kerry: or redirect to `https://www.mysite.co.za/` directly everywhere.

Comment: This rule won’t force HTTPS. It will only force the host name to start with `www.`

Comment: @Gareth: Thanks for clearing this up Gareth, I was wondering if that may be the case. IF the browser checks the SSL match against the domain name before the server does it's thing then it renders the possibly of prefixing the www to the url in an https situation impossible!

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: This wont work, as Gareth mentioned and as I tested, the site indeed throws an SSL Security warning / error before one has a changes to redirect.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes I am aware of this, I have other htaccess rules in the non ssl directory of the site to force SSL, but if the user rocks u on an already SSL'd link, no need to force SSL, this htaccess rule resides in the publi_ssl part of the site, and the only requirement is to force the www to the url, which I am no almost certain is not possible!

Comment: @EVERYONE - Just to clear the air, the only VIABLE solution around this was to get another SSL certificate for the domain in question. Wild card certificates that support sub domains will work as well. The issue is simply that the call to verify the SSL certificate on the domain happens before any .htaccess rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone point out a way to add the www to the domain when the domain starts with HTTPS and not HTTP?

So you want this:

- If the host does not start with www:

  - If the connection is secure, do nothing. In this case you're already screwed anyway, because the user has already seen the host mismatch warning.
  - If the connect is not secure redirect to https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Your current rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This rule fails on you because it adds www no matter whether the connection is secure or not. Additionally, it keeps plain http the way it is (no forward to https://).

The rule that satisfy your requirements above is

```
#if the host does not start with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#and the connection is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =""
#forward
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

The `L` flag is unnecessary because a redirect ends the rewriting.

Comment: Thanks Artefacto, this code clears some smoke for me, however to be clear I have another .htaccess file present on the non SSL directory which redirects to the https with no problem, even if the www is left out, it will prepend it and send the user to the secure site. The issue still lies with the secure directory.

Are you telling me that no amount of rewrite rules can add the www prefix to the url if the user lands on https://mysite.co.za because the browser has checked the certificate before the rules are applied? I need to know if the only solution is to have two SSL Certificates?

Comment: if the user goes to https://mysite.co.za, the certificate will be presented before the user sends the hostname he's requesting, so apache cannot decide certificate to send. You'd need not just another certificate, but another IP address as well. However, you can get a certificate that is valid both for mysite.co.za and www.mysite.co.za. Most current web browsers support those certificates.

Comment: Of course you can have two certificates, one for mysite.co.za and one for www.mysite.co.za as those are theoretically two different domain names. You do not need to have one common certificate that supports both domains.

Comment: @webfac You do need to have a certificate that supports both domains if they resolve to the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but it's certainly a way around the problem:

SSL certificates from Digicert will by default protect both WWW and non-WWW variants of the same domain. I don't know of any other mainstream certificate authority which does this - [Digicert SSL Plus](http://www.digicert.com/welcome/ssl-plus.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this, however the client has just bought a new Thawte certificate a month ago. Besides I'm not sure what the reputation of 'Digicert' is? There are alternatives, Thawte offer a 'Web Server' certificate where you can add variants of a domain name onto the certificate at a fraction of the cost of a new certificate. It's all one big money making market aint it! Thanks for your suggestions however, they don't go unnoticed.

Comment: Fair enough, and it's tough if you've just bought a new certificate (there may be a grace period). If you can take my word for it (I don't work for them, I'm just a webdev), Digicert are pretty top notch. They're supported in all web browsers, they're a fraction of the price of Thawte/Verisign, and they've got the best support in the world (I've never had a question they couldn't answer on the spot in live-chat, and they sent me a t-shirt trans-Atlantic, with a hand-written letter, just because one of our clients tweeted that I'd recommended them to him).