# How can I use mod_rewrite to redirect to a https connection?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to always redirect people to

```
https://www.somedomain.com/URL
```

when they come in on a non secure port. This is because my SSL is for this url.

When someone goes to http://www.somedomain.com they get sent to

```
http://www.www.somedomain.com
```

Here is the htaccess rewrite that i am trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Edit:

I am using a cPanel server, so making additional hosts is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to always redirect people to `https://www.somedomain.com/URL`

I think this is all you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.somedomain.com/$1   [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to not unconditionally add the www, if it already exists.
See: [Prepend 'www' to an HTTPS url using .htaccess & mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902590/prepend-www-to-an-https-url-using-htaccess-mod-rewrite?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `mod_rewrite` is not the preferred way to do that. Using virtualhosts it's simpler. Just put this configuration (Source: [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL#Using_mod_rewrite)):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.somedomain.com
   Redirect permanent /secure https://www.somedomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName www.somedomain.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```